# Time series - best approach?

Tags: regression, time-series, autoregressive

Good evening, newbie to the forum but I would appreciate some advice on a new problem I’m working on. We are collecting water samples and measuring a number of things simultaneously in the water, as well as the general environment, including one particular parameter known as turbidity. We want to be able to 1) forecast future turbidity levels and 2) know if there a statistically significant change in the time series for this level.

I was going to sue a traditional multivariate time series approach (i.e VAR/Vector Auto Regression). We only have 10's of data right now, maybe 100's to 1000 in the future.

I'll be really interested to know if a time series approach is a sensible  start the problem. Or is a regression/ML approach better (obviously the latter is  a bit restricted for the time being due to limited dataset size)

Comment: This is a fair question, but it's important to note that there's no real general answer to "is there a statistically significant change in the time series for this level". Statistical significance is defined based on the model you have in mind. If you give me a time series data set showing any size of change, I can come up with potential models where that change is significant, and models where it isn't. You'll need some theoretical justification for the model you pick.